# How to View Android API Code

Tags: android

I would like to see the source code for the API in the android platform. For example see what is under android.widget.ImageView.Class. However I get source code not found in eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find ImageView source code here:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/ImageView.java

The project source code is not going to visible in eclipse unless you've got your self a copy of the source. It is not included in the SDK by default.

Answer (score 1):

Here is link for [Android source](http://source.android.com/source/index.html) and another [link for repository](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/). You need to attach source code for your project to see the source in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Source code for all API packages(including their classes and methods) can be found at [Android API packages Source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android)

Main domain/website is: [android.googlesource.com](http://android.googlesource.com)

In the first hyperlink, among all the packages mentioned at [developer.android.com/reference/packages.html](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html), you will only find source code for those packages that start with name *android*.